# Is there a JavaScript chart library that supports sharing an axis among multiple charts?

Tags: javascript, charts, frameworks, bar-chart

I am looking for a non-transpiled JavaScript library that supports multiple charts with a shared axis.

Like these 2 bar graphs, which share the vertical Y-axis for country labels:

[image: example]

The three most popular charting libraries, ECharts, PLotly.js & Charts.js, do not appear to support this and nothing like it appears in their example showcases.

Comment: Maybe put two charts side by side and hide the y-axis of the right chart?

Comment: I did that with ECharts, but this causes a couple problems: 1) The Y-axis must be its own chart to prevent it from shrinking when the charts shrink due to page-resize. 2) Responsiveness of the Y-axis label chart must be handled manually.  3) Normalization of the X-axis across all charts would have to be handled manually.  This causes another problem: 3) Normalization of X-axis tick spacing must  be handled manually.  It would be easier to code the entire chart from scratch using HTML/JS/CSS, which defeats the purpose of the library.